# Import updated version of database in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, synchronization

So I have this PostgreSQL database which I dumped and copied to another server. On that new server I updated rows and also added tables.

Now I would like to "sync" the new one over the old so that they both have the same state again - is that possible?

Thanks in advance

Comment: It's going to be difficult.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you will need to have a dump created on your machine2 and import it back into machine1. There is a tool pgdiff available, which maybe helps you to find differences, but to be fair I never tried it.